# DNX Install - Unable to find any runtime packages on the feed

Tags: dnx, dnvm

I'm following [this guide](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html) on how to get setup with asp.net 5

Running the command `dnvm upgrade -r clr` from the command line pulls back

```
Invoke-Command : Unable to find any runtime packages on the feed!
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\dnvm.ps1:1905 char:23
+         Invoke-Command <<<<  ([ScriptBlock]::Create("dnvm-$cmd $cmdargs"))
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Unable to find ...es on the f
   eed!:String) [Invoke-Command], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unable to find any runtime packages on the feed!
   ,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

I've pulled down the latest power shell script [from here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/dev/dnvm.ps1).

Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

It's something related to proxy authentication, but I'm not sure what needs added where.

Trying to Update DNVM to the latest: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: What DNVM version do you use?

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci  Running dnvm -v yields v1.0.0-beta5-10384

Comment: That's very old. Install the latest version by following the instructions here: https://github.com/aspnet/home

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci The DNVM update command shoots back a 407 Proxy Authentication required message when trying to run it. I'll put a screenshot in the question

Comment: Either get the file manually like described on the github page or do update-self with the -Proxy option

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci Does the proxy option work for you? putting in the same settings I use for other apps work here.

Answer (score 2):

If you are upgrading behind a proxy server, try adding `-Proxy` option:

```
dnvm upgrade -Proxy <server>:<port>
```

Comment: Using the -Proxy flag gives the same message but from line 1451 of the powershell script.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the environment variable http_proxy to "server:port".

e.g.

`$env:http_proxy='myproxy:8080'`

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved in beta8 scripts.

For now, you'll need to [download the script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1) manually and try running it manually.

Since the script is using `[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials`, you might have some chance in setting it in a Powershell Console before invoking the script.

Sample:

```bsh
[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials.Username = "user"
[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials.Password = "pwd"
[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials.Domain = "domain"
```

Here's the [matching GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/858).

Comment: Aren't the commands on that issues pull request https://github.com/aspnet/Home/commit/17bd0c8e61ee175c54fea9af753d42f74632486d?diff=split the same as the instructions https://github.com/aspnet/home

Comment: Sure look like it. I was more thinking of downloading the dnvminstall.ps1 manually with your browser. Added link to my answer.

Comment: Gotcha, running the command by hand is sending back those 407 Proxy Authentication Required messages. I did try to set my user/pass ahead of time using the [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials.Username = "user" commands you added in the answer but no luck sadly.

Comment: Make sure that the username/password/domain are set to the right value. Check also with your sysadmin to ensure that you are using the right values for your proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I just test latest `dnvm.ps1` dev script but default proxy is still not passed automatically. Because I don't want to write my password anywhere, as temporary solutions I have edited dnvm.ps1 script to this (last block of Apply-Proxy method):

```
function Apply-Proxy {
param(
  [System.Net.WebClient] $wc,
  [string]$Proxy
)
  if (!$Proxy) {
    $Proxy = $env:http_proxy
  }
  if ($Proxy) {
    $wp = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy($Proxy)
    $pb = New-Object UriBuilder($Proxy)
    if (!$pb.UserName) {
        $wp.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
    } else {
        $wp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($pb.UserName, $pb.Password)
    }
    $wc.Proxy = $wp
  }
  else {  # edit start
    $wc.Proxy=[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy;
    $wc.Proxy.Credentials=[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials;
  } # edit end
}
```

And it works. I hope he script will be modified somehow in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I got all kinds of errors (including the one you have mentioned) and were apparently all related to the proxy. setting up the proxy fixed it.

setup either from command line or from the environment variables of your machine

setx http_proxy http::my_proxy_ip_address:port

finding out the combaination of correct ip and port was the biggest challenge for me -;) (and drove me nutts-;)

Did a quick recording while fixing it just in case it helps anyone https://youtu.be/RbYYWS-ZwFY